# Probability and Computer science question

Tags: probability, computer-science, random

We are given a function **rand()** that returns a random number from the segment **[0,1]**,
how can we use this function to create a size $100$ **uniform** array,
 of exactly **$50$ $0's$** and **$50$ $1's$**.

Comment: Off-topic question aside.  How can you call the required array *random*?

Comment: Fixed, something got lost in translation there, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Can you add any extra content to your question?

Comment: Still, that's better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Its an interview question, they asked for an algorithem to solve this problem.

Comment: Usual shuffle algorithm: fill the array with 50 0s and 50 1s, then for each element index idx and random sample s switch the element at 100*s with the element at idx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea:

1. Create an array $a$ with 100 zeroes. I'll assume that array index is zero based.
2. Set counter to zero.
3. Create integer $i$ in the following way: $i=(int)(100*rand())$. This returns a random index between 0 and 99 (inclusive).
4. If $a(i)=1$, repeat step 3. If not, set $a(i)=1$ and increment the counter.
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 as long as counter < 50

Second idea:

1. Create an array of 100 random values between 0.0 and 1.0
2. Find $M$, the median value of the array (basically a value such that 50 generated values are smaller and 50 generated values are bigger than it). There are algorithms for that that run in linear time. Full explanation can be found [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/median-finding-algorithm/).
3. Go through the list again and replace all values smaller than $M$ with 0 and the rest with $1$.